# Insert calculated values of an array into a new array

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have a function `computeNormal` that I want to perform a calculation on values stored in an array (value - rounded mean value of the array), then store the results in another array and print them in my other `compute` function.

This is my code, but it returns the wrong values. What am I doing wrong?

```
int computeNormal(int normals[], int measurements[], int nrOfMeasurements)
{
    int sum = 0, normal = 0;
    float mean;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfMeasurements; i++)
    {
        sum += measurements[i];
    }
 
    mean = ((float)sum/nrOfMeasurements);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfMeasurements; i++)
    {
        normal = measurements[i] - round(mean);
        normals[i] = normal;
    }
 
}
```

```
void compute(int measurements[], int nrOfMeasurements)
{
    int normals[nrOfMeasurements];
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfMeasurements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", computeNormal(normals, measurements, nrOfMeasurements));
    }
    printf("]");
    printf("\n");
}
```

nrOfMeasurements = The amount of input values the user has entered, between 1-10 that has been assigned in an `enter` function, measurements[] = The array that stores the original input values, normals[] = the array I want to print my calculated values.

Comment: `computeNormal` is declared to return a value, and you use that returned value. But what does `computeNormal` actually return? It seems to me that it should be declared to return *nothing* (i.e. `void`), then you call it *once* to copy your calculated values to the `normals` array. Then your loop only prints the values in the `normals` array.

Comment: Also, in `computeNormal` the `normal` variable isn't really needed, you can assign directly to `normals[i]`.

Comment: You are indeed right, thank you for the advice. I changed it to declare it to `void` instead. How do I go about calling it once to copy the calculated values to the `normals` array though?

Comment: Just like any other function, i.e. `computeNormal(normals, measurements, nrOfMeasurements);`?

Comment: Doing that gives me the compiler error "Invalid use of void expression". Any ideas why?

Comment: Then you're probably still trying to use the result of the call as argument to `printf`. You need to call the function separately, once. And then use the results it put into the `normals` array. As shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call the `computeNormal` function to let it do its calculations and save it into your array.

Then print the values from the array.

Like this:

```
computeNormal(normals, measurements, nrOfMeasurements);

for (int i = 0; i < nrOfMeasurements; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", normals[i]);
}
```